# Ladda is not defined with node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have two ladda buttons on two different pages rendered by node.js along with bootstrap components in my application.

I have the Ladda installed using `bower install ladda`.

**home.jade**

```
button.btn.btn-primary.makeSearch.ladda-button(data-style='expand-left')
span.ladda-label home
```

**login.jade**

```
button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block.ladda-button(data-style='expand-left')
span.ladda-label Login
```

**common.js**

```
var l = Ladda.create(this);
l.start();
```

However, I get

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Ladda is not defined`

But the spinner works fine without any error for one button in one first page, whereas I get an not defined error for the other button.

Comment: please add your HTML structure.. and make sure your ladda.js library file loaded before Ladda button create.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your are missing `ladda.min.js` and `spin.min.js` files!

Please read [Instructions](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda) carefully.

The compiled files for the project that you should be using are available in the /dist directory. You will need to include both the ladda.min.js and spin.min.js files as well as ONE of the two style sheets. If you want the button styles used in the Ladda example page use the ladda.min.css file, if you want to have the functional buttons without the visual style (colors, padding etc) use the ladda-themeless.min.css file.

Comment: including those files doesn't solve the issue. In the output, Ladda is still not defined.